Change of variables via Jacobian with Voigt notation for differential operator
I'm reading Non-linear Finite Element Analysis of Solids and Structures (De Borst, R., Crisfield, M. A., Remmers, J. J., & Verhoosel, C. V).
As part of the weak form of the governing equations of motion, the operator $\mathbf{B} =\mathbf{L}\mathbf{H}$ appears where
$$\mathbf{H} = \begin{bmatrix}h_1 & 0 & 0 & h_2 & 0 & 0 &...\\ 0 & h_1 & 0 & 0 & h_2 & 0 &...\\ 0 & 0 & h_1& 0 & 0 & h_2& ... \end{bmatrix}$$
is a $3\times 3n$ matrix, $n$ is the number of nodes in an element and $h_k = h_k(\xi, \eta, \zeta)$ are the shape functions parameterised according to a local standard coordinate system. $\mathbf{L}$ is a shorthand differential operator allowing to define divergence with respect to global coordinates $(x,y,z)$ for a symmetric second order tensor (e.g. Cauchy stress, small strain) as $\nabla\cdot\boldsymbol{\sigma} = \mathbf{L}^T\boldsymbol{\sigma}$ where $\boldsymbol{\sigma} = \left(\sigma_{xx}, \sigma_{yy}, \sigma_{zz}, \sigma_{xy}, \sigma_{yz}, \sigma_{xz}\right)^T$ and
$$\mathbf{L}^T = \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} & 0 & 0 & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & 0 & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\\0 & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & 0 & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} & 0\\ 0 & 0& \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} & 0 &\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\end{bmatrix}$$
When changing coordinates from global spatial coordinates to a fixed element-local system, the authors claim the operator $\mathbf{B}$ can be written
$$\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{J}^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\xi} & 0& 0 & \dfrac{\partial h_2}{\partial\xi}& 0 & 0&...\\0&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\eta}&0&0&\dfrac{\partial h_2}{\partial\eta}&0&...\\0&0&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\zeta}&0&0&\dfrac{\partial h_2}{\partial\zeta}&...\\\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\eta}&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\xi}&0&\dfrac{\partial h_2}{\partial\eta}&\dfrac{\partial h_2}{\partial\xi}&0&...\\0&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\zeta}&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\eta}&0&\dfrac{\partial h_2}{\partial\zeta}&\dfrac{\partial h_2}{\partial\eta}&...\\\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\zeta}&0&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\xi}&\dfrac{\partial h_2}{\partial\zeta}&0&\dfrac{\partial h_2}{\partial\xi}&...\end{bmatrix} $$
for some inverse Jacobian matrix $\mathbf{J}^{-1}$ represented in $6\times6$ form with "the appropriate entries filled in". I cannot seem to obtain such a Jacobian representation that satisfies all entries of the product $\mathbf{B}=\mathbf{L}\mathbf{H}$. Perhaps the mapping is non-linear? Any indicators would be appreciated.

Forget about the matrix being "Jacobian" and just focus on finding what 36 elements you need by the chain rule.
$\begin{align}\mathbf X &= \mathbf J\mathbf{LH}\\[1ex]&=\begin{bmatrix}j_{11}&j_{12}&j_{13}&j_{14}&j_{15}&j_{16}\\j_{21}&j_{22}&j_{23}&j_{24}&j_{25}&j_{26}\\j_{31}&j_{32}&j_{33}&j_{34}&j_{35}&j_{36}\\j_{41}&j_{42}&j_{43}&j_{44}&j_{45}&j_{46}\\j_{51}&j_{52}&j_{53}&j_{54}&j_{55}&j_{56}\\j_{61}&j_{62}&j_{63}&j_{64}&j_{65}&j_{66}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & 0 \\ 0&0 & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\\ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} &0\\ 0& \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial y}\\ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z} & 0 & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}h_1 & 0 &0&...\\ 0 & h_1 & 0 &...\\ 0 & 0 & h_1& ... \end{bmatrix}\\&=\begin{bmatrix}j_{11}&j_{12}&j_{13}&j_{14}&j_{15}&j_{16}\\j_{21}&j_{22}&j_{23}&j_{24}&j_{25}&j_{26}\\j_{31}&j_{32}&j_{33}&j_{34}&j_{35}&j_{36}\\j_{41}&j_{42}&j_{43}&j_{44}&j_{45}&j_{46}\\j_{51}&j_{52}&j_{53}&j_{54}&j_{55}&j_{56}\\j_{61}&j_{62}&j_{63}&j_{64}&j_{65}&j_{66}\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial x} & 0 &0 &\cdots\\0&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial y}&0&\cdots\\0&0&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial z}&\cdots\\\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial y}&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial x}&0&\cdots\\0&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial z}&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial y}&\cdots\\\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial z}&0&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial x}&\cdots\end{bmatrix}\\[1ex]\begin{bmatrix}\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\xi} & 0& 0 &...\\0&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\eta}&0&...\\0&0&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\zeta}&...\\\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\eta}&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\xi}&0&...\\0&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\zeta}&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\eta}&...\\\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\zeta}&0&\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial\xi}&...\end{bmatrix}&=\begin{bmatrix}j_{11}\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial x}+j_{14}\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial y}+j_{16}\dfrac{\partial h_1}{\partial z}&\cdots\\\vdots&\ddots\end{bmatrix} \end{align}$
